# Can an Android Context inside an activity be static?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, static, android-context

I have a static function in which I need to access my color resources. In order access color resources I need context variable which is static. I am confused if I can make context static. Is there any side effects to it? or, is there any other way I can access my resources without using context

Here is the function

```
 private static SpannableStringBuilder setTextColor(
      SpannableStringBuilder Text, int spanLength, boolean isSuggestion) {
    addressText.setSpan(
        new ForegroundColorSpan(
            context
                .getResources()
                .getColor(
                    isSuggestion ? R.color.blur: R.color.red)),
        addressText.length() - 1 - spanLength,
        addressText.length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return Text;
  }
```

Comment: Could you show all the related code?

Comment: Post a code snippet with an example, and is never a good idea to keep the context into a static variable.

Comment: It is best if you can provide your code. For your information, it is not a good idea to make a context static as it can lead to memory leak.

Comment: updated the question with code

Comment: Why don't just pass `Context` as method parameter that will be limit to the method scope .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am confused if I can make context static. Is there any side effects
>   to it?

You can declare a context as static but it is not recommended in Android, because it might lead to a memory leak in your app.

> is there any other way I can access my resources without using
>   context?

No, you need a context instance to access resources in your app.

Back to your case, the easiest way is passing a context as param of the method.

```
private static SpannableStringBuilder setTextColor(Context context, SpannableStringBuilder Text, int spanLength, boolean isSuggestion) {
    int color = context.getResources().getColor(isSuggestion ? R.color.blur : R.color.red);

    addressText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color),
            addressText.length() - 1 - spanLength,
            addressText.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    return Text;
}
```

Inside your activity, pass `this` as context when calling `setTextColor`, for example.

```
setTextColor(this, new SpannableStringBuilder(), 0, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, you can achieve this by creating a class that extends Application and storing the application context in the companion object.

Usually it will look similar to this:

```
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        private var instance: App? = null
        val context: Context?
            get() = instance?.applicationContext
    }
}
```

And you can access the context anywhere via `App.context`

In regards to your concerns about storing a static context, if you were storing an activity or fragment context then you risk creating memory leaks, but since we're storing the application context which is tied to the lifecycle of the entire application, there won't be any issues with memory leaks.

You may run into issues if you want to write testable code that depends on a static context, in which case I would recommend you pass the context into the function rather than access it directly.

Answer (score -2):

1) Create your App class which extend Application

```
private static Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
```

2) Create getApplicationContext() method which return context

```
public static Context getApplicationContext() {
  return context;
}
```

3) Now you can get context anywhere in your class like

```
Context context = App.getContext().getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: is it a good idea to use application context ?do it cause any side effects

Comment: This is one kind of approach and every application should have App class to initialize and control UI. There is nothing wrong & why you think that it's may cause side effect? If you don't like just leave it, please don't put negative like.

Comment: I didn't put the negative like.